# how to find an existing number in an specific tag, but this tag is existing more than one time (beautifulsoup)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to find the value 280 that is in the `bdi` tag. I've tried to track it by using the `findAll` method but it gives me another existing number in another `bdi` tag

**HTML Format**

[image: img]

**Code**

```py
def function():
    price=soup.findAll('bdi')[4].get_text()
    return price
```

##### Output

```
199
340
```

Comment: if possible can you share the URL please!

Comment: yes sure , https://www.maroc4gaming.net/index.php/produit/erxung-j5-blue/

Comment: indices start at `0` so if you want the fourth item, the correct index is `3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First find main HTML tag which containt that `bdi` price tag and based on
> that i have used `find_all` method on `div`  tag and from that on
> index 0 data is present so we can fetch according to it!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get('https://www.maroc4gaming.net/index.php/produit/erxung-j5-blue/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
```

Here in the code i have used list compherension and for loop in alternative condtion

```
main_data=soup.find_all("div",class_="price-wrapper")[0].find_all("span",class_="woocommerce-Price-amount amount")
price_len=len(main_data)

if price_len==1:
    price=[i.text.split("\xa0")[0] for i in main_data]
    print("Latest Price" + " " +price[0])
else:
    price=[i.text.split("\xa0")[0] for i in main_data]
    print("Latest Price" + " " +price[1])
```

Output:

```
'280.0'
```

Comment: that was great , but I have another issue , if u can look this website it has a promotion in the price,  so when I run this code , it gives me the value of 300 https://www.maroc4gaming.net/index.php/produit/casque-gamer-jedel-gh-230/

Comment: do you know a way how can i not print the oldest price ?